# Using scp to copy a remote file containing spaces requires double space escaping. Why?

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

I was trying to copy a file from a remote machine to my machine using scp. The problem I was facing arose when the path to the remote machine contained some spaces like:

```
scp userxxx@100.100.100.100:/home/userxxx/Documents/folder 1/test.txt /home/userxxx/Documents/folder_1/
```

This obviously did not work stating:

> scp: /home/userxxx/Documents/folder: No such file or directory
> scp: 1/test.txt: No such file or directory

I tried the methods I knew about escaping spaces like with backlash:

```
scp userxxx@100.100.100.100:/home/userxxx/Documents/folder\ 1/test.txt /home/userxxx/Documents/folder_1/
```

and with quotes:

```
scp userxxx@100.100.100.100:'/home/userxxx/Documents/folder 1/test.txt' /home/userxxx/Documents/folder_1/
```

but both failed.

The only method I found working was combining them (!) (suggested in [here](https://www.linuxshelltips.com/escape-spaces-in-paths-for-scp-in-linux/)):

```
scp userxxx@100.100.100.100:'/home/userxxx/Documents/folder\ 1/test.txt' /home/userxxx/Documents/folder_1/
```

So, my question is why does this happen? Does this mean that the remote path (since I think the problem occurs in remote path only) is being parsed twice for some reason and so applying only one escape method does not work?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right 'that the remote path is being parsed twice'. Maybe parsed once in the client and once in the server. I tested with `scp` and with `rsync`, and both are affected by this problem with files names with a space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable **printing command traces before executing a command** with `set -x` to see what is actually being passed to `scp` in the three cases like so:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/test$ mkdir 'folder 1'
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/test$ touch 'folder 1'/test.txt
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/test$ mkdir foldr_1
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/test$ set -x


ubuntu@ubuntu:~/test$ scp ubuntu@localhost:/home/ubuntu/test/folder\ 1/test.txt /home/ubuntu/test/foldr_1/
+ scp 'ubuntu@localhost:/home/ubuntu/test/folder 1/test.txt' /home/ubuntu/test/foldr_1/
ubuntu@localhost's password: 
scp: /home/ubuntu/test/folder: No such file or directory
scp: 1/test.txt: No such file or directory


ubuntu@ubuntu:~/test$ scp ubuntu@localhost:'/home/ubuntu/test/folder 1/test.txt' /home/ubuntu/test/foldr_1/
+ scp 'ubuntu@localhost:/home/ubuntu/test/folder 1/test.txt' /home/ubuntu/test/foldr_1/
ubuntu@localhost's password: 
scp: /home/ubuntu/test/folder: No such file or directory
scp: 1/test.txt: No such file or directory


ubuntu@ubuntu:~/test$ scp ubuntu@localhost:'/home/ubuntu/test/folder\ 1/test.txt' /home/ubuntu/test/foldr_1/
+ scp 'ubuntu@localhost:/home/ubuntu/test/folder\ 1/test.txt' /home/ubuntu/test/foldr_1/
ubuntu@localhost's password: 
test.txt                                                                                                       100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
```

So, as you see in the first and second cases, the splitting happens on the remote machine because the escapes are not passed to it … while in the third case with double escaping(*that apparently can also be achieved by using both double quotes and single quotes together i.e. `'" ... "'` or a triple backslash i.e. `\\\`*) e.g.:

```
scp ubuntu@localhost:'"/home/ubuntu/test/folder 1/test.txt"' /home/ubuntu/test/foldr_1/
```

or

```
scp ubuntu@localhost:/home/ubuntu/test/folder\\\ 1/test.txt /home/ubuntu/test/foldr_1/
```

the escapes are passed to the remote machine and the path translates correctly … basically with remote clients like `scp`, `ssh`, `sftp` and `rsync` ... etc. alike, when issuing those commands from your local machine(local shell) with file path/s in their arguments, you need to provide escapes twice(*or protect the escape character/s from being consumed/used by your local shell*) once on the local machine and another on the remote machine.