# Bash script variable with a space

Tags: bash, scripts

I try to write a bash script for copying data from one folder to another.

```
Source="/My Images/"
Target=/Transfer/Media/
rsync -avu --progress $Source $Target
```

The problem is, that the script can not find the folder "/My Images/", because there is a space between those two words.

How do I tell the variable Source to accept this folder name?

Comment: Double quote `"$Source"` ... And as a good measure `"$Target"` as well as you should get into the habit of quoting parameters in your scripts ... i.e. `rsync -avu --progress "$Source" "$Target"`

Answer (score 3):

> How do I tell the variable Source to accept this folder name?

It's not assigning that parameter:

```
Source="/My Images/"
```

but rather its expansion:

```
rsync -avu --progress $Source $Target
```

As it appears you already know that quoting the path/string `"/My Images/"` is necessary to handle the space in it.

You will also need to quote the parameter/variable containing it when you use it in the command to prevent word splitting by the shell like so:

```
rsync -avu --progress "$Source" "$Target"
```

You should get into the habit of double quoting all parameters in your scripts.

I assume you are using `rsync` locally on the same machine, but if you are using it to synchronize files to a remote machine using `ssh` for example, then you might need to double quote/escape ... See for example: [Using scp to copy a remote file containing spaces requires double space escaping. Why?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1414882)