# Opening applications on Windows 10 Virtual Machine from Ubuntu 23.04/23.10 with VBoxManage guestcontrol

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, 23.04, guest-additions, 23.10

#### VBoxManage guestcontrol [vmname] run/start

I managed to open *Calculator* on my Windows 10 guest VM from my Ubuntu 23.04 host using the command:

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol $MY_VM_NAME run --exe "C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe" --username $MY_USERNAME --password $MY_PASSWORD
```

#### Problem

However, when doing the same for *WordPad*, *Microsoft Office applications* or *Adobe Acrobat Reader*, it doesn't work:

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol $MY_VM_NAME run --exe "C:\\Program Files\\Windows NT\\Accessories\\wordpad.exe" --username $MY_USERNAME --password $MY_PASSWORD
```

Note: `run` and `start` give the same results.

#### Details

On the Ubuntu host, when I execute the last command, the cursor flashes and the prompt is never returned. In the Windows 10 VM, looking at the *Task Manager*, I note that the application (*WordPad* in this example) appears in the **background processes** list. When I try, using the same command, to execute a personal script I've converted into .exe file instead of an application, the outputs I'm used to see in the guest Windows "Terminal" appear in the host Ubuntu Terminal (see Test section below). ***It is like if the *guestcontrol* process attempts to redirect the output of the app to the host.*** However, I don't know why I have no problem when opening *Calculator*.

[image]

Using the `--verbose` option returns:

```
$ VBoxManage guestcontrol $MY_VM_NAME start --verbose --exe "C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe" --username $MY_USERNAME --password $MY_PASSWORD
Executing:
  Image : C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe
  arg[0]: C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe
Creating guest session as user 'toto'...
Waiting for guest session to start...
Successfully started guest session (ID 8)
Starting guest process ...
[1284 - Session 8]
Wait result is 'started' (1)
Process successfully started!
Guest session detached

$ VBoxManage guestcontrol $MY_VM_NAME start --verbose --exe "C:\\Program Files\\Windows NT\\Accessories\\wordpad.exe" --username $MY_USERNAME --password $MY_PASSWORD
Executing:
  Image : C:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe
  arg[0]: C:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe
Creating guest session as user 'toto'...
Waiting for guest session to start...
Successfully started guest session (ID 9)
Starting guest process ...
[8812 - Session 9]
Wait result is 'started' (1)
Process successfully started!
Guest session detached
```

#### Ubuntu, Windows and VirtualBox tested versions

I got same results for both VirtualBox v6.1 and v7.0. I've also tried with VMs created from `Win10_21H2_English_x64.iso` and `Win10_22H2_English_x64v1.iso`. However, no matter the version of VirtualBox, if I'm using **Ubuntu 22.04**, then it works perfectly.

EDIT 1: Exact same behavior on **Ubuntu 23.10** than on **Ubuntu 23.04**.

EDIT 2: The problem is still going on with **VirtualBox v7.0.12**.

#### Test

I've create a HelloWorld script that I converted to an executable file on the guest. From the host, when I do

```
toto@toto-pc:~$ VBoxManage guestcontrol $MY_VM_NAME run --exe "C:\\Users\\Toto\\Desktop\\runapp\\runHello.exe" --username $MY_USERNAME --password $MY_PASSWORD
Hello, World!
toto@toto-pc:~$
```

note that "Hello, World!" shows up in the Terminal of my host instead of the guest.

Comment: Just a thought as I don't have the means to try it at the moment ... You seem to double escape the backslashes (once with the quotes and another with an extra backslash) ... This is common practice needed when the line will be parsed by two shells (local and remote) See for example: [Using scp to copy a remote file containing spaces requires double space escaping. Why?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1414882) ... Therefore try double escaping the spaces in the path of second command as well i.e. `"C:\\Program\ Files\\Windows\ NT\\Accessories\\wordpad.exe"`.

Comment: I've tried. It returns an error. Please note that the command of my post seems to respond since WordPad starts in the VM. However, it starts as a background process.

Comment: I have tried it and both commands worked (both apps opened in the foreground) ... But, `run` seems to wait for `wordpad` until it's closed while `start` instead worked as expected ... So try that like: `VBoxManage guestcontrol $MY_VM_NAME start --exe "C:\\...` ... If that didn't work then most likely it's a Windows issue.

Comment: I quickly looked into some documents and manual pages for the difference between the two and couldn’t find clear explanation yet … I will however keep looking or even trace both when I have time … Meanwhile `start` is most likely certainly the one to use for your purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

The issue comes from **VirtualBox Guest Additions v7**. Downgraded to a v6 version solve the problem.

### Details

- Host OS: Ubuntu 23.10
- Guest OS: Windows 10
- VirtualBox: v7.0.10

1. In the Windows 10 VM, uninstall *Oracle VM VirtualBox Guest Additions* (Control Panel > Uninstall a program).
2. Power off the VM.
3. Download the ISO file from an older version of the VirtualBox Guest Additions [here](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/). Works with `VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.48.iso`.
4. (Optional) Save the ISO file under `~/.config/VirtualBox/`.
5. In the VirtualBox Manager, choose the ISO file for **SATA Port 1: [Optical Drive] VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.48.iso**.
6. Start the VM.
7. Under "This PC", double click on **CD Drive (D:) VirtualBox Guest Additions**, then on `VBoxWindowsAdditions.exe` and follow the instructions to install VirtualBox Guest Additions v6.1.48.

### Note

None of the VirtualBox Guest Additions v7 seems to work. Then, since only the VirtualBox Guest Additions v6 are working, it is maybe better to also use VirtualBox v6 instead of VirtualBox v7.

Answer (score 5):

#### Preface

This answer is merely informative and is not intended to be a complete solution to the question ... Although, it could be.

#### Ubuntu side of things

There are two similar commands of interest for the `guestcontrol` utility, `run` and `start` which are slightly different ... From the documentation for [**VBoxManage guestcontrol**](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-guestcontrol):

> **Run a Command on the guest**
>
> ```
> VBoxManage guestcontrol 
> run [--arg0=argument 0] [--domain=domainname] [--dos2unix]
> [--exe=filename] [--ignore-orphaned-processes] [ --no-wait-stderr |
> --wait-stderr ] [ --no-wait-stdout | --wait-stdout ] [ --passwordfile=password-file | --password=password ] [--profile] [--putenv=var-name=[value]] [--quiet] [--timeout=msec] [--unix2dos]
> [--unquoted-args] [--username=username] [--verbose]
> ```
>
> The **VBoxManage guestcontrol vmname run** command enables you to execute
> a program on the guest VM. Standard input, standard output, and
> standard error are redirected from the VM to the host system until the
> program completes.

... and:

> **Start a Command on the guest**
>
> ```
> VBoxManage guestcontrol  start [--arg0=argument 0] [--domain=domainname]
> [--exe=filename] [--ignore-orphaned-processes] [
> --passwordfile=password-file | --password=password ] [--profile] [--putenv=var-name=[value]] [--quiet] [--timeout=msec]
> [--unquoted-args] [--username=username] [--verbose]
> ```
>
> The **VBoxManage guestcontrol vmname start** command enables you to
> execute a guest program until it completes.

... So, as you can see, the one you should use is the **latter**(*i.e. `start`*) as the former will keep the standard I/O streams of the guest process open and redirect them to the terminal on the host (*or more precisely connect them*) thus resulting in some applications that can accept/expect input before they start like a file argument to open in the case of "WordPad" to keep waiting and not fully load and hold the prompt in the terminal on the host ... while simple applications like "Calculator" which appear to not be aware of those I/O streams disconnects them immediately and starts (*i.e. as far as the process on the host knows, the command on the guest has terminated and the I/O streams are disconnected and therefore, the prompt in the terminal is freed and restored*).

#### Windows side of things

There are limitations ... The Windows OS imposes certain limitations for graphical applications. See [Chapter 14, Known Limitations](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch14.html) ... Which are:

> **Guest control**. On Windows guests, a process started using the guest
> control execute support will not be able to display a graphical user
> interface unless the user account under which it is running is
> currently logged in and has a desktop session.

... and:

> Also, to use accounts without or with an empty password, the guest's
> group policy must be changed. To do so, open the group policy editor
> on the command line by typing `gpedit.msc`, open the key Computer
> Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local
> Policies\Security Options and change the value of Accounts: Limit
> local account use of blank passwords to console logon only to
> Disabled.

... and other experimental features that **might** cause issues affecting GUI applications:

> Some Oracle VM VirtualBox features are labeled as experimental. Such
> features are provided on an "as-is" basis and are not formally
> supported. However, feedback and suggestions about such features are
> welcome. A comprehensive list of experimental features is as follows:
>
> - Hardware 3D acceleration support for Windows, Linux, and Oracle
>   Solaris guests
> - Hardware 2D video playback acceleration support for Windows guests
> - ICH9 chipset emulation
> - EFI firmware
> - Using Oracle VM VirtualBox and Hyper-V on the same host

#### My advice

Use the available option `--verbose` to see what is actually happening (*reporting from the guest side might be limited by what Windows chooses to report or not report*) like for example so:

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol $MY_VM_NAME start --verbose \
--exe "C:\\Program Files\\Windows NT\\Accessories\\wordpad.exe" \
--username $MY_USERNAME --password $MY_PASSWORD
```

Comment: The prompt in the terminal is freed when using `start`. However, both `run` and `start` options open the app as a background process in the guest. Note that generally I'm using a file argument such as `-- WINWORD/arg0 "Z:\\Path\\To\\My\\File.docx"`.

Comment: @TVG Your `--verbose` output shows that on the Ubuntu side there appears to be no problem ... So, I'd focus on the Windows side of things.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Note that it works fine on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Any finding on the Windows side? Are you definitely sure this is not a Ubuntu 23.04 problem since it works fine on Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: @TVG *"Are you definitely sure...?*" ... From what I know about how things work, I'd say almost definitely sure ... But, Let me trace it (*the communication between host and guest*) in depth and try to reproduce the problem if I can then I will report back to you with a definite verdict ... Hopefully today if I get some free time or else probably tomorrow :-)

Comment: @TVG Confirmed ... I am, now, definitely sure this is not a Ubuntu 23.04 problem ... And I couldn't reproduce the problem by the way which suggests it's not a general Windows issue but rather specific to the version of Windows you use or the Windows setup you have ... So, try with a vanilla new Windows installation and it will most likely work for you as well ... I used `Win10_21H2_Arabic_x64.iso` for the guest.

Comment: I've tried with a new Windows installation (`Win10_21H2_English_x64.iso`) and I got the exact same result. I can open Calculator but not WordPad.

Comment: @TVG That is strange indeed … I couldn’t reproduce the problem at all and both apps worked opening in the foreground every time … I apologize for not being able to help as everything in my test environment worked as expected and I have traced the communication on both Ubuntu 22.04 and 23.04 and they were both identical in that regard which leaves me with nothing evidence-based that I can suggest … Sorry :-)

Comment: I've just try with another ISO file (`Win10_22H2_English_x64v1.iso`). I still get the same issue. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate!

Comment: I've upgraded to Ubuntu 23.10. Unfortunately, that did not solved the issue.

Comment: I've another PC with Ubuntu 22.04 and VirtualBox 7.0.12 on which the VBoxManage guestcontrol works fine. I upgraded to Ubuntu 23.04 and it continued to work fine until I upgraded the VirtualBox Guest Additions. Did you upgraded the VirtualBox Guest Additions when you tried to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @TVG No, I didn't IIRC ... You seem to have found the culprit :-)

Comment: Maybe but I don't find how to go back to a working system.

Comment: @TVG They are supposed to install inside Windows ... So Control pannel --> Add/Remove Programs --> uninstall it ... Alternatively there might be an uninstall script on the Guiest Additions CD

Comment: Thank you! I was able to downgrade to the older version Guest Additions 5.2.10 and it works fine! I'll try to fix it on my main PC too.

Comment: @TVG Well done, you found it … It turns to be a Windows issue afterall and not Ubuntu's :-)

Comment: It is more a VBoxGuestAdditions issue. On my old PC, I am able to select an older version of the Guest Additions that I installed before. However, on my new PC, I don't have any other ISO file to choose and I'm not sure I can download an old ISO file.

Comment: @TVG That discovery is worth an answer for sure, please add it.

Comment: Sure. I'm trying to find a way to solve the problem on my new computer first in order to provide a more complete answer.

Comment: I've added an answer. I noted it works for any GA v6 and does not work for GA v7. However, I'm not sure it is recommended to use VB v7 with GA v6.

Comment: @TVG I've already seen your answer and upvoted it ... I am happy that you kept investigating until you found the culprit ... I don't know about the versions compatibility though.