# rsync remote paths with spaces and autocompletion is not working

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, rsync, auto-completion

Running Ubuntu 22.04

I have a remote server that I can connect to with ssh.

```
ssh remote
```

So I can copy a file with rsync:

```
rsync remote:text.txt .
```

`rsync` will autocomplete tex to test.txt when I press tab

I have another file 'test file.txt', containing a space, that rsync will autocomplete and escape to

```
rsync remote:test\\\ file.txt
```

But then it fails to execute:

```
rsync: [sender] link_stat "/home/user/test\ file.txt" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1865) [Receiver=3.2.7]
rsync: [Receiver] write error: Broken pipe (32)
```

How do I fix this `rsync` autocompletion escape problem?

**Using** `scp` it does work:

```
scp remote:test\\\ file.txt .
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using scp to copy a remote file containing spaces requires double space escaping. Why?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414882/using-scp-to-copy-a-remote-file-containing-spaces-requires-double-space-escaping)

Comment: @Raffa. No, it does work in scp (auto-completion and copying)

Comment: What I was hinting at is to actually try another escaping mechanism manually ... I don't know how that command is translated on your system ... But, it appears that `rsync` does double escapes automatically ... And yet it treats one of those double escapes as actually part of the filename `... link_stat "/home/user/test\ file.txt" failed ...` ... I could be wrong, but it appears that you might need to escape only once in that situation ... Worth a try nonetheless.

Comment: @Raffa, found an issue with rsync, added it as an answer.

Comment: That's what I thought ... Thank you for letting me know and well done.

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with newer `rsync` versions (> 3.2.4) and (older) versions of bash-completion.

https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/pull/910

As a workaround use the `--old-args` argument.

```
rsync --old-args remote:test\\\ file.txt
```

This works.

And much easier than removing the double slashes in the path:

```
rsync --old-args remote:test\ file.txt
```

Also works.